# Netbeans push 401 error

Tags: git, netbeans, github

Hi, I'm trying to use the GIT plugin,

I have changed files and now I'm trying to push files to my git repo.

`right click -> git -> add`,

`right click ->git -> commit`,

I put my username and password to repo, choose branch [master] -> [master]
And I got `401 Authorization Required`. Password is 100% correct. I don't know what to change to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same problem.  It looks to be a known issue over on the [NetBeans site](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204376).  As of the latest comment (14 Nov), the fix is available in the beta development builds of version 7.1.  The fix will *not* be delivered for version 7.0.1 of NetBeans.

Comment: Yes I'he seen this. Only think that left is to push from consol.